# Wildfly stops when running in debug mode in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, wildfly, jboss-tools

I installed Eclipse and the Jboss Tools plugin with Wildfly.

I can run Wildfly in Eclipse in non-debug mode with no problems. But when I start Wildfly in debug, I can use it for a few minutes, and then it suddenly stops processing, the server ends.

I checked the log and there's nothing. What could be wrong?

Comment: Stops meaning wildfly process ends or the process pauses on a debug breakpoint?

Comment: meaning that it ends processing, if you see the status under the server tab it says `Stopped`

Comment: What is the version of eclipse and JBoss Tools?

Comment: JBoss Tools 4.9.0, Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0) and Wildfly 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note the JBoss Tools 4.9.0 is validated against 2018-09 but not against 2018-12.
Do you see something in the server log when the server dies ?

Comment: There's nothing in the log

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue and it was because we changed our config to close the management port, which had been used to detect that the server had started. Eclipse could no longer detect that the server had started, so it shut down the process after a set time (450 seconds)

To resolve the issue, we did the following in the Eclipse's Overview panel for our JBoss Server:

- Changed the Start Timeout to 30, so it would only fail if it actually couldn't start in 30 seconds rather than waiting for 450
- Changed our "Server State Detectors" to detect a Web Port for Startup Poller and Process Terminated for Shutdown Poller.
- Changed the Server Ports to match our new configuration

Excerpt from [JBoss Community Archive](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/249386)

> The tooling was unable to verify your server started. Our tooling has several methods to see if your server is up or not. The two most-often used methods are either "Web Port Poller" or "Management Poller".
>
> You can see which your server is using by opening the server object (In Servers view, double-click your server) and on the right side you'll see a section on polling.
>
> If your server adapter (fancy word for the tooling's representation of your server) is using the Management Port Poller, you should make sure your server is actually exposing the management port. For local servers this shouldn't be an issue, since local servers should automatically expose the management port. You may want to verify in the Ports section (also in the server editor) that the management port is correct.  To check if the server is up, we run a management command against the server. If the server responds properly, we declare the server to be started.
>
> If you're using the web port poller, then you may want to verify your web port is correct. To verify the server is up, the Web Port Poller opens a URL connection on {serverHost}:{webPort} and sees if we get a valid connection.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Eclipse plugin will listen to 'Web Port' (in Server State Detectors - Startup Poller -setting). The web port defaults to 8080 which in my case is not really in use -> thus the start will timeout and WildFly is shutted.

In my case I was using 443 as Web port, but somehow this didn't work and I really didn't use time to solve, but I figure that has something to do with SSL and start poller not supporting ports responding SSL.

I changed Startup Poller to "Management Service" and voilá, immediately started to work.

Main thing is to set "Server State Detectors" (Startup Poller and Shutdown Poller) and optionally the "Server Ports" section so that they match your WildFly configuration:
[image]